# Positioning multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position, flexbox

I am new to the world of HTML5. I want some help with CSS layouts. I have tried lots of solutions I have seen in StackOverflow. I could able to get it working but with using fixed positioning. I would like something more dynamic.

I created a sample in plunker.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/nXxN17?p=preview
```

In the sample:

```
index1.html => all div's are fixed except center element.
index.html => my requirment.
```

The issue here is, if I increase listview content, by changing pagesize to 50 or 100, the listview expands vertically pushing the content down. I want listview to fill the remaining height and activate scrolling when it's content becomes larger.

Basically, I am looking for main body to be non-scrollable. All content should be with in main page and have the center element scrollable, in this case kendo ui listview.

This is my requirement.

```
body
div - 40px;
div - maxHeight: 100px; - header
div - height:30px; (pager)
div - height: * (kendo ui listview) - fill height and scrollable
div - maxHeight: 100px; - footer
div - height: 40px; - buttons always stays on bottom
```

Edit:
As suggested to try using flex, I did, but still not able to get the center element to fill the container to the max and not push the content down.
updated plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VaRdti?p=preview

Please help - Thanks

Comment: Please explain better your problem, so we can be of more help, from your demo, everything seems to be in order. If your problem is with the center view generating an scroll, maybe you could sum the fixed heights, and set the listview with `calc(100% - 310px)` so the window will stay scroll-less...

Comment: There is a big difference between needing and wanting help.

Comment: @Rakesh Are you asking for an Android ListView?

Comment: @joaoBeno I added some more details. I cannot use calc, as I don't the height of header and footer. header and footer can be empty or fill to it's max height. So I want center view to fill the remaining height and scroll if it's content larger.  please try increasing the page size to 50 or 100.

Comment: @Rakesh try using flexbox then... Here is what you need to know to get it working: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks @joaoBeno, I will look into flex box. I am using bootstrap too, can we get this using grid system. just want to know if i miss anything.

Comment: The grid on bootstrap is only horizontal, not vertical, while flexbox will allow you to solve your vertical distribution problem the way you wish...

Comment: I tried with flex-box, still no success. I need to make center element fixed height, but I don't know size. Is there a way to get remaining content size. Here is the update plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/VaRdti?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using Flexbox. Initially i didn't get using flex box as I need to support in IE 10. By adding additional vendor prefixes, i am able to meet the given requirement.

```
Visit http://plnkr.co/edit/VaRdti?p=preview
```